Calculating depth of the circuit - why can depth for full adder be 1?
The depth of the multiplier is 14 , but I have a different result so I think I misunderstood something about the depth.
My full adder and half adder looks like this: 
I'm trying to do something in assembly. Before doing that, I would like to find out the depth of the circuit. I thought that a full adder (here VA) has a depth 3? There are two different critical paths but what confuses me is that sometimes there is 1 or a 2 on the VA indicating its depth , but how can it be 1/2 if a full adder alone has depth 3?
This adder is based on the principle that the partial products pp3, pp2, pp1, pp0 are not added sequentially but in parallel. The two intermediate results are added together in a carry ripple adder at the end, whereby it is never possible for x1 and x0 to both be 1.
I am really lost here

Calculating maximum path - i wanted to add 3 when there is a full adder and 1 when there is a half adder - however, this is supposed to be incorrect. Why can a full adder have a depth value of 1 or 2 as well here?

It depends on the design of the (full) adder circuit.  One can design a full adder to optimize (minimize) the delay from Cin to the outputs, and that is often a good choice for ripple-carry designs.

I attached a picture of my full adder circuit in the post.
Since I always take the same full adder - how could it possibly be one there for example ? The critical path for a single full adder is always 3?

Your full-adder only has depth 3 from a/b to c_out.  Depth from c_in to s is only 1.  That's a bit weird -- usually one would design the circuit to minimize depth from c_in to c_out.

Thank you - I thought I would have to use the longest path. Why can I use the depth from c_in to s here then?

Each different path-length (latency) matters depending on how early that input is ready.  When you're drawing a line through multiple blocks and looking at it as a potential critical-path, you use the latency from the inputs and outputs you're passing through.  Your green and red lines are mostly going sideways, ripple-carry propagation, where as @ChrisDodd says it would have been a good idea to design the full-adder to minimize that latency.

Just FYI, real-world multipliers normally avoid this problem by not fully propagating carry at every step.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dadda_multiplier
